How can I install Laminate Flooring Around Drain
I work from home in an outbuilding one of the previous homeowners built. They also ran city water to a valve inside of the outbuilding and put a drain in the floor near the valve. The drain runs down under part of our yard back to the crawlspace under the house where a sump pump feeds it into the home's drain pipes.
I'm starting the process of installing some Pergo Timbercraft + WetProtect. The drain has me pondering how to work around it. It's not vital at the moment and I'm confident no water will get in after having worked out there for the last year.
As for the specifics: the floor grades down to the drain about 12 inches from center. The grade is about 1 inch.
Is there a specific method I should use to install laminate flooring around the drain?



You will probably need to use some self levelling compound around the drain.  Hard flooring types, planks/tiles do not like dips/ridges.  A small piece of drain pipe, 3 or 4 inch diameter and about an inch tall, that fits will keep the drain open.

@crip659 this is what I ended up doing. Thank you

The laminate floor, no matter the make or brand will conform to the depression around the drain.
It will need to be made flat, flat enough to be within the guidelines of most laminate floor suppliers, to be within an 1/8" or 3/16" flat using a 4' or perhaps a 6' straightedge.
Your flooring pack will have the particulars they require to keep it from separating at the joints or cracking

This sounds like a nice job to have a wide piece of plastic to fit over and leave a flat floor.  I am open to licensing/royalty deals.

@crip659 Where is the drain in the midst of this plastic, obviously below the plastic you speak of, but with a hole in it to see the drain, or covering the drain? I suppose the edges of the plastic since it will need to be pretty thick to keep it from deflecting, would be accurately tapered to meet the concrete floor properly.... Perhaps a steel plate instead....

I was thinking of passages on the underside of the plastic to pass water to the drain.  Maybe accessible hole in the centre if OP wants to add a sink.

It will conform, but I need to make it flat?

It, in my opinion needs to be flat. One, because it will void the warranty, another because the material, when it drops down in the "drain cone" it may crack at the point it begins to drop. And lastly, the geometry needed for the flooring to stay locked together will be violated. The material will need to stretch in width and length to maintain a lock onto the surrounding pieces. Picture this, run a straight piece across the drain, with no dipping, mark the ends, then push it down to the bottom. It will move from one or both of the marks. it will need to do this in both directions to conform.

The answer I gave is in response to the question, as is the way this forum is set up. Actually, if you are certain that there will be no water on the floor at all, except for cleaning purposes, block the drain with a bit of cement first, let it set up overnight, and use cement to flatten the floor to the tolerance need to lay the floor.

Lose the drain and use a floor leveler.
